# Why does vim CursorMoved event triggered in this script?

Tags: vimscript

I'm writing a vim script. When `fun()` is called, I want a new window of 3 lines height is opened, with the content of register `h` displayed. And then, when the user moved the cursor, like `hjkl`, the window is closed automatically.

The code just like below. But I found the CursorMoved event is tiggered unexpected. Therefore, The window which was supposed to display and wait for user input is just flashed and closed.

Why the autocmd in `fun()` is executed as soon as it is installed?

Is there anything I missed or wrong?

```
let t:tmpname = tempname()

function! s:CloseWin()
    let l:c_nr = bufnr("")
    let l:p_nr = bufwinnr(t:tmpname)
    exec l:p_nr . " wincmd w"
    close
    exec bufwinnr(l:c_nr) . " wincmd w"
    autocmd! vgroup
endfunction


function! s:fun()
    let @h = 'xxxx'
    silent! topleft 3 new
    silent! exec "edit " . t:tempname
    silent! 1,$delete _
    silent! put h
    silent! call cursor(1, 0, 0)
    silent! delete _

    silent! setlocal noswapfile
    silent! setlocal buftype=nofile
    silent! setlocal bufhidden=hide
    silent! setlocal nowrap
    silent! setlocal foldcolumn=0
    silent! setlocal foldmethod=manual
    silent! setlocal nofoldenable
    silent! setlocal nobuflisted
    silent! setlocal nospell
    silent! wincmd p

    augroup vgroup
        autocmd!
        autocmd CursorMoved * call s:CloseWin()
    augroup end
endfunction
```

Comment: Had anyone ever found a solution for this? I'm hitting the _exact_ same issue. (tmp window that I want to close on cursor moved)